How do I save a ffmpeg stream from another device?
I am streaming a desktop capture using ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts udp://IP:PORT . I can use ffplay -f mpegts udp://IP:PORT to play the streamed video on another device. How can I save the streamed video to the second device?
I have tried ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://IP:PORT output.mp4 but this doesn't appear to work.
Edit for clarification: I am streaming video from device A. I can play the streamed video to device B. I would like to save the video streaming from device A to device B. The output video file should be located on device B. The first command I run on device A. The other two commands I am running on device B.

Your title says "...save... FROM another device" and your question body says "...save... TO the second device". Could you please clarify which it is? Also, are you trying to capture the video on one device and just save it to a different one, or are you trying to CAPTURE the video ALSO on the second device? If you map a network drive/folder from the second device to the capturing device, you should be able to specify that path in your output path.

@music2myear I am streaming video from device A. I can play the streamed video to device B. I would like to save the video streaming from device A to device B. The output video file should be located on device B. The first command I run on device A. The other two commands I am running on device B.

Could you perhaps edit your question to clarify that? Pretty much what you said in the comment should be said in the question to make that understandable.

So, after continuing to tweak my commands, I figured out what I was doing wrong.
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts udp://IP:PORT
In this command, the IP:PORT was correctly set to device B, and I assumed that I would need to use the exact same IP:PORT for the command I was running on device B. Instead, because the video was being streamed to that local IP, I needed to use the local 127.0.0.1:PORT instead.
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts udp://DeviceB_IP:PORT to stream the video and ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://127.0.0.1:PORT output.mp4 to save the streamed video to a file.
